# Updating Select List Custom Field - Jira Python

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-java-api

I have a custom field named "*Status*" with an id of 10100 which is a **select list** with optional values of "*One*", "*Two*", "*Three*" and "*Four*". Default value is "*One*".

I am writing a JIRA python script to update the value of this field conditionally. Say if the existing value is "*One*", it should be changed to "*Two*".

This is my code.

```
from jira.client import JIRA
jira_options={'server': 'http://localhost:8080'}
jira=JIRA(options=jira_options,basic_auth=('usrname','pwd'))

for issue in jira.search_issues(' cf[10100] = "One" '):
    issue.update(fields={'customfield_10100': 'Two'})
```

It's giving me the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    issue.update(fields={'customfield_10100': 'Two'})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jira\resources.py", line 193, in update
    super(Issue, self).update(**data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jira\resources.py", line 72, in update
    raise_on_error(r)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jira\exceptions.py", line 29, in raise_on_
error
    error = errorMessages[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Could you please tell me what might be wrong?
I had used the same syntax for editing a custom field of type **text field** and it had worked fine.

Comment: Is the value supposed to be an array?

Comment: Sorry, I didnt get the query @mdoar You mean the values for the options in the select list ?
While defining the custom field I gave it as strings only.

Comment: While trying to solve this issue I also observed that even though the custom field (select list) with the id 10100 exists, the request `http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10100` ended up in giving me an error.
`{"errorMessages":["A custom field option with id '10100' does not exist"],"errors":{}}`
Weird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
issue.update(fields={'customfield_10100': {'value':'Two'}})
```

or like this:

```
issue.update(fields={'customfield_10100': {'value','Two'}})
```

I am not sure which one will work out for you because I never worked with Python, but one of them should work.

Comment: The second one is not valid python, but the first one worked for me too.

Comment: @jalanb The second one is valid Python, `{'value', 'Two'}` evaluates to a set

Comment: Yes, of course it is valid. Must've been off my meds that day.